Booting in UEFI success but some drivers are missing
I have a legacy BIOS Kubuntu 22.04 install on a hard drive from another old Laptop, while I have another hard drive other OSs are installed on it in UEFI. However, From my mainbaord's BIOS/UEFI I terminated the CSM comparability and then the Legacy BIOS hard drive does not appear in the UEFI boot menu. However, there is an entry called Fedora when I choose it, it boots my Kubuntu 22.04 and it booted successfully without any error messages and I can login as ordinary as booting in CSM, but there is a bunch of missing drivers, such as WiFi, Audio etc
screenfetch
./+o+-       said@Satellite-L850-A700
yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.11.12-300.fc34.x86_64
.++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 55m
.:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 4058
o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: fish 3.3.1
.:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1440x900
.++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: KDE 5.92.0 / Plasma 5.24.7
/+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: KWin
\+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   GTK Theme: Aritim-Light-GTK [GTK2/3]
.++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   Icon Theme: Amy-Light-Icons
.+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Disk: 156G / 570G (29%)
\+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650G with Radeon Graphics @ 12x 3.7GHz
`:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      GPU: AMD Radeon Graphics (renoir, LLVM 17.0.4, DRM 3.40, 5.11.12-300.fc34.x86_64)
.o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      RAM: 2751MiB / 11899MiB
/osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/
````` +oo+++o\:
`oo++.

As seen from screenfetch output, my old laptop is shown, while my current PC is a desktop based on AMD Ryzen and AsROCK steel legend mainbaord. Also the Firmware version is very old.
I tried to run sudo apt update to get the new drivers, but it does not work.
